# How can I iterate through an object containing arrays in React and the object is in the state

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

Hello I have a component that has a state that contains an object and the object contains 6 arrays:

```
this.state = {
obiect: {
cif: [],
data_creare: [],
detalii: [],
id: [],
id_solicitare: [],
tip: []
}
```

After I add values to the arrays with setState from an api call I would like to display the arrays in a HTML table.

How can I iterate through the object`s arrays so I can display them on the table rows ?

I tried this.state.obiect.map(...etc and it gives me an error.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the code where you try to access this.state ?

Comment: `obiect` is still an object, you'll need `this.state.obiect.cif.map(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic iteration using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const state = {
  obiect: {
    cif: [1,2],
    data_creare: [3,4],
    detalii: [5,6],
    id: [7,8],
    id_solicitare: [9, 10],
    tip: [11,12]
  }
};

Object.entries(state.obiect).forEach(([k,v]) => {
  console.log(k, v);
  v.forEach(ele => console.log(ele));
});
```

If you want to access the arrays horizontally you can find the longest one and use a `for` loop.

```js
const state = {
  obiect: {
    cif: [1,2],
    data_creare: [3,4],
    detalii: [5,6],
    id: [7,8],
    id_solicitare: [9, 10, 13],
    tip: [11,12]
  }
};

const maxL = Object.values(state.obiect).reduce((a, b) => (a = a > b.length ? a : b.length, a), 0);

for (let i=0; i<maxL; i++) {
  let row = ''
  Object.entries(state.obiect).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    const value = v[i] ?? '-';
    row += `${k}: ${value} `;
  });
  console.log(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the different objects in object with `this.state.object.slice()`. And for these objects you need .map `this.state.object.id.map()`

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over an object's properties you can use `for...in` [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
let state = {
  obiect: {
    cif: [],
    data_creare: [],
    detalii: [],
    id: [],
    id_solicitare: [],
   tip: []
  }
}

for(let i in state.obiect){
  console.log(`${i} : ${state.obiect[i]}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.obiect)) {
  // object1[`${key}`].map(...) here for dynamic array
}
```